# the number of distinct elements in product sets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A programming assignment asked to two **disjoint** 3-element sets such that the product set has size 5.

> $\big| \{x\,y : x \in \{a,b,c\}, \;y \in \{d,e,f\},\; x \neq y\}\big|=5$

If we have two disjoint n-element sets, $A,B$ define a product operation $AB$ as

> $ A* B = \{ x\, y : x\in A, y \in B \}$

We have that $1 \leq |A*B| \leq n^2$.

Can we always find two sets, whose product set has a particular size?  What is the minumum number of elements we can have in $ A * B $ ?

Comment: If $A=B$ is a geometric progression of $n$ terms, the product set can have $2n-1$ terms. This question is usually asked for sumsets instead of products --- application of logarithms indicates there's not much difference. There is a huge literature on sumsets.

Answer (score 2):

One way to produce $|A*B|=(|A|-1)(|B|-1)+1$ (as would be useful for the task at hand) is to have $0\in A$ and $0\in B$ (and fill up with distinct primes for example). However, this trick is prohibited by the disjointness requirement.

One way to produce $|A*B|=|A|+|B|-1$ (as would also be helpful for the task at hand) is to take consecutive powers of the same base, such as $A=B=\{2^0,2^1,2^2\}$ as that produces $A*B=\{2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4\}$. Again, $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint. But this time this can be cured by multiplying all elements of $B$ with a suitable constant (for example $B=\{3,6,12\}$).

What numbers can be achieved if $|A|=|B|=n\ge 2$?

The method above gives us $|A*B|=|A|+|B|-1=2n-1$.

**Lemma.** If all elements of $A$ are positive and at least one element of $B$ is positive, then $$\tag0 |A*B|\ge |A|+|B|-1.$$

*Proof:* The element $a_1:=\min A$ of $A$ give us $n$ distinct elements $a_1\cdot b\in A*B$ and each additional element $a\in A$ gives us at least $a\cdot \max B$ as additional element of $A*B$ because it is bigger than all $a'b$ with $a'<a$. $_\square$

**Corollary.** If all elements of $A$ have the same sign, then $|A*B|\ge|A|+|B|-1$.

*Proof:* The case $n=1$ is ttrivial. Otherwise $B$ has at least one nonzero element. Negate all elements of $A$ and/or $B$ if necessary to ensure all ements of $A$ are positive and at least one element of $B$ is positive. That at most negates the elements of $A*B$ without changing their number. $_\square$

Let $m$ be an integer with $n\le m\le (n-1)n $. Then there exists a sequence
 $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n$ of integers with $a_1=0$, $a_k+1\le a_{k+1}\le a_k+n$ for $1\le k<n$ and $a_n=m$.
Let $$\tag1A=\{3,6,12,\ldots, 3\cdot 2^{n-1}\}\quad \text{and}\quad B=\{2^{a_1},2^{a_2},\ldots, 2^{a_n}\}.$$
Then 
$$\begin{align}A*B&=\{3\cdot 2^k\mid 0\le k\le a_n+n-1\}\\\end{align}$$
 has $n+m$ elements.
Thus all values with
$$2n-1\le |A* B|\le n^2$$
can indeed be achieved.

In the light of th elmma/corollary above, we may ask: 
Is it possible to go below $2n-1$ if we allow nonpositive elements?
If $n=2m$ is even, we can let 
$$\tag2A=\{\pm3,\pm6,\pm12,\ldots, \pm3\cdot 2^{m-1}\}\quad \text{and}\quad B=\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\ldots, \pm2^{m-1}\}.$$
Then 
$$ A*B=\{\pm3\cdot 2^k\mid 0\le k\le 2m-1\}$$
has $4m-2=2n-2$ elements.